# Loop in R using API

Tags: r, api, loops, limit

I want to have a loop to retrieve data from this function listOMLRunEvaluations the function has a limit=10000. How can I make a loop in R to call this function either by task.id= i or by limit and offlimit (retrieve every 10000 rows in each iteration).

Comment: Please make this question *reproducible*. This includes sample code (including listing non-base R packages), sample data (e.g., `dput(head(x))`), and expected output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `for` loop with `Sys.sleep()` in case you also have a limit of request per second:

```
result <- c()
for(i in 1:10) {
new <- listOMLRunEvaluations()
result <- c(old, new)
Sys.sleep(10)
}
```

Comment: Strongly recommend against the concept of building a response vector like this. I'd suggest rather you do something like `l <- lapply(1:10, function(i) ...)` and then `unlist(l)`: it may not be much faster in the smaller scale, but without this method larger-scale problems will gradually become slower as R has to reallocate and copy all data for `result` through each iteration.

Comment: can you please explain more in using lapply in my functionlistOMLRunEvaluations @r2evans

Comment: Bayan, I'm generally willing to help, but ... what is there for me to help with? Perhaps you mean `result <- unlist(lapply(1:n, function(ign) limitOMLRunEvaluations()))`? I know nothing about your process, if you present a reproducible question I might be able to provide more help.